# How to remove Neovim trailing white space?

Tags: neovim, autocmd, whitespace, lua

In Vim I used `autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e` to delete trailing white space on save. Now, Neovim 0.7 has the new `vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd`.

What is the correct syntax to adapt this `autocmd` in Lua?

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePre", {
  group = "Format",
  buffer = bufnr,
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufWritePre" }, {
  pattern = { "*" },
  command = [[%s/\s\+$//e]],
})
```

Be sure to read the `h:nvim_create_autocmd()` for more info!

Comment: It works for me. Try running `:checkhealth` or seeing if your neovim version is up-to-date with `$ nvim -v`

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the accepted answer.
Something that begins to annoy quickly is that the cursor position is reset to the beginning of the line.
To keep it, one can use `getpos`/`setpos` like this:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufWritePre" }, {
    pattern = {"*"},
    callback = function(ev)
        save_cursor = vim.fn.getpos(".")
        vim.cmd([[%s/\s\+$//e]])
        vim.fn.setpos(".", save_cursor)
    end,
})
```

To catch errors use pcall()

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufWritePre" }, {
    pattern = {"*"},
    callback = function()
      local save_cursor = vim.fn.getpos(".")
      pcall(function() vim.cmd [[%s/\s\+$//e]] end)
      vim.fn.setpos(".", save_cursor)
    end,
})
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might be interested in `winsaveview()` and its counterpart. To be safe you need try/finally or vim9’s defer, also.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be setup to only run on a keyboard shortcut.

The following command when executed in `n - Normal Mode` followed by the Leader key `\` + `wt`.

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<Leader>wt', [[:%s/\s\+$//e<cr>]])
-- mode     ----^
-- shortcut ---------^
-- command  ----------------------^
```

I like to go one step further and wire up the lsp format command like the following example, notice the `<bar>` symbol allows for multiple commands:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<Leader>wt', [[:lua vim.lsp.buf.format()<cr> <bar> :%s/\s\+$//e<cr>]])
-- mode     ----^
-- shortcut ---------^
-- command1  -----------------------^
-- bar      ------------------------------------------------------^
-- command2  -----------------------------------------------------------^
```